# onenote problem for lastModifiedDateTime property

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am working on onenote page API and extract data from onenote page content. Currently, we have a condition to check recently updated (30 minutes ago) pages based on lastModifiedDateTime and retrieve and process them.

I am using ms graph endpoint to check updated pages. The problem is when I update something one the page the `lastModifiedDateTime` doesn't updated. I can see the content is updated even page title isn't updating instantly.

[image]

I have updated the content of this page yesterday but still it's `lastModifiedDateTime` isn't updated. Is it a bug or something I am missing to get latest date-time?

Any help would be really appreciated. Stuck here for a long time.

Comment: How do you update the page? With the Graph API or manually by editing the page in OneNote app?

Comment: manually by editing the page in OneNote web

Comment: This is strange. It works fine on my side. Tried to edit page from both OneNote Desktop and OneNote Web and lastModifiedDateTime was updated.

Comment: I tried it with several onenote pages but `lastModifiedDateTime` isn't updating.

Comment: Is the content itself updated? When calling Graph API, do you see the changes you've made?

Comment: Yes, every time the content is updated but that property isn't updating.